# Rails text_area popup?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, popup

So basically I have a new post form and What i want is if the user clicks the insert html tag button then a text area field should popup (but the submit button will still have to be on the main page).

Answer (score -1):

you can use css transition property

```
#dialog{
opacity:0;
z-index:-1;
transition: all 0.5s linear;
} 
.Clicked{
 opacity:1;
 z-index:1;
 }
```

and add the neccessry class in javascript when the buttonn is clicked

```
document.getElementById("dialog").className = "Clicked"
```

hope it helped